# Node.js `crypto.final` make the encrypted result is different to PHP `mcrypt_encrypt`

Tags: php, node.js, encryption, mcrypt

### At first, Node.js crypto.

```
// Both of key and IV are hex-string, but I hide them in Stackoverflow.

var secretKey  = new Buffer('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa', 'hex'), // 48 chars
    iv         = new Buffer('bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb', 'hex'); // 16 chars
var str        = 'This string will be encrypted.';
var cipher     = crypto.createCipheriv('des-ede3-cbc', secretKey, iv),
    cryptedStr = cipher.update(str, 'utf8', 'base64') + cipher.final('base64');
```

### Then, PHP mcrypt.

```
$key    = pack('H*', "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"); 
$iv     = pack('H*', "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"); 
$string = 'This string will be encrypted.';
$text   = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, $key, $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
$text_base64 = base64_encode($text);
```

### Problem.

In the same string, same algorithm and same encoding.

Still there is a little part not match that is `cipher.final()`.

Below is the real sample output.

```
// Node.js output.
UKBI17EIHKNM2EU48ygsjil5r58Eo1csByAIFp9GhUw=
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    Same part

// PHP output.
UKBI17EIHKNM2EU48ygsjil5r58Eo1csAY4C0JZoyco=
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    Same part
```

Why `cipher.final()` make results different?

How could make the same results in Node.js **on condition that don't modify PHP code**.

Comment: The node.js example results in an error: http://runnable.com/VUcebtM0NhY3v9v5/output

Comment: I see, I don't know how to make it visible. Anyway, the error is: "buffer.js:348 ret = this.parent.hexWrite(string, this.offset + offset, length); TypeError: Invalid hex string".

Comment: @GergoErdosi, you right. I fixed it. Because previous article that I wrote the  odd chars for Buffer.

Comment: Do you know which output is the correct one?

Comment: I dont know which is correct. But I must be follow the PHP result. I used Node.js to connect other people's PHP system.

Comment: The problem is in the padding which I told you already in the previous question.

Comment: Sorry, I added the description for the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you can't change your PHP code, you will need to modify the node.js code.

The problem is that node.js' crypto module uses only PKCS#7 padding, whereas PHP uses only zero padding. You can however disable padding in node.js ([`setAutoPadding(false)`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_cipher_setautopadding_auto_padding_true)) to implement your own zero padding:

```
function zeroPad(buf, blocksize){
    if (typeof buf === "string") {
        buf = new Buffer(buf, "utf8");
    }
    var pad = new Buffer((blocksize - (buf.length % blocksize)) % blocksize);
    pad.fill(0);
    return Buffer.concat([buf, pad]);
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var secretKey  = new Buffer('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa', 'hex'), // 48 chars
    iv         = new Buffer('bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb', 'hex'); // 16 chars
var str        = 'This string will be encrypted.';
var cipher     = crypto.createCipheriv('des-ede3-cbc', secretKey, iv);
cipher.setAutoPadding(false);

var cryptedStr = cipher.update(zeroPad(str, 8), 'utf8', 'base64') + cipher.final('base64');

console.log(cryptedStr);
```

Output:

```
UKBI17EIHKNM2EU48ygsjil5r58Eo1csAY4C0JZoyco=
```

Here is an implementation of a matching unpad function:

```
function zeroUnpad(buf, blocksize){
    var lastIndex = buf.length;
    while(lastIndex >= 0 && lastIndex > buf.length - blocksize - 1) {
        lastIndex--;
        if (buf[lastIndex] != 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return buf.slice(0, lastIndex + 1).toString("utf8");
}
```

Comment: I fixed one line. It can work now. Thank you ver much!!

Comment: return Buffer.concat([buf, new Buffer(Array((blocksize - (buf.length % blocksize)) % blocksize).join('00'), 'hex')]);

Comment: This line `new Buffer(num)` , seem get the random output. So I make it be ('00', 'hex')

Comment: Turns out the buffer needs to be filled. It is not guaranteed that it is filled with zero bytes. I changed for a clearer implementation. For some reason it worked the first time I tested this. I also added an unpad function